# Skew image unto another image

Tags: vb.net, draw, skew

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.
I have a main background image, and I want to skew an image and add it to the main background.

[image]

So far I have this:

```
'Create a new bitmap image of the transparent image

Dim overlay As New Bitmap("C:\TestFolder\rectangle.png")

'Create a new bitmap image of the image to you want the transparent image drawn onto

Dim pic As New Bitmap("C:\TestFolder\MyImage.png")

'Create a graphics object from the image to be drawn onto

Dim grx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)

'Draw the transparent image into the picture

grx.DrawImage(overlay, 100, 100)

'Dispose the graphics object

grx.Dispose()

'Save the new image that you just put the transparent image on

pic.Save("C:\TestFolder\NewImage.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

'Dispose both new bitmap images because they are not needed anymore

overlay.Dispose()
pic.Dispose()
```

I managed to draw the image on top of another one, but I'm not able to skew it and put in the right place using pixel location.

**EDIT**
I also added this code:

```
Dim destinationPoints As Point() = { _
    New Point(518, 0), _
    New Point(743, 0), _
    New Point(518, 288), _
    New Point(743, 377)}

Dim image As New Bitmap("C:\TestFolder\this.png")

' Draw the image unaltered with its upper-left corner at (0, 0)

e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 518, 0)

' Draw the image mapped to the parallelogram

e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationPoints)
```

But everytime I run it, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in WindowsApplication4.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skew Image and add to another Image in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097640/skew-image-and-add-to-another-image-in-visual-basic)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot illustrating what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Neolisk here's the link for the image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/UFsw2.png

I can't add the image in the post since i don't have a reputation of 10. NO COPYRIGHT INFRINGEMENT INTENDED.

Comment: Ok, we are getting there. You posted two pieces of code. Please specify where they belong, i.e. which event handler or override.

Comment: @Neolisk The first piece of code works. It belongs to a button, and merges the two pictures i put in the TestFolder.

The second piece of block belongs to a button as well, and is supposed to skew the image i want.

The process is to click the button to the skew image, and then click the button to merge the two images together.

Comment: `e.Graphics` cannot belong to a button, because button does not have `Graphics` under it's `e` variable in the event handler signature.

Comment: @Neolisk what should i do then ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom PictureBox, you can further expand it to add properties specifying background and overlay images, as well as dynamically calculate scaling factors. I cut images from your question using MsPaint and saved them as two separate files. To use, drop this new control on the form, and make sure image files exist at the specified locations.

```
Public Class CustomPictureBox : Inherits PictureBox

  Sub New()
    Me.Image = New Bitmap("C:\Admin\image_background.png")
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pe As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(pe)

    Dim image As New Bitmap("C:\Admin\image_overlay.png")

    Dim szScale As Size = image.Size
    szScale.Width /= 4.5
    szScale.Height /= 2

    Dim ptLocation As Point = New Point(98, -17)

    Dim destinationPoints As Point() = {
      ptLocation,
      ptLocation + New Point(szScale.Width, 20),
      ptLocation + New Point(0, szScale.Height)
    }

    pe.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationPoints)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

Using these two files:

[image] and [image]

You can play with parameters to ensure better fit, but it should be good enough to prove the concept.

**Note:** Why you may have got problems with it, is because you need 3, not 4 destination points to form a parallelogram, as specified in this article:

- [How to: Rotate, Reflect, and Skew Images @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So i created a new form, copied the code you wrote, and added a PictureBox. When i try to build it, i get 3 errors :

`-Error 3 'Image' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication7.CustomPictureBox'. `
///
`-Warning 2 'Public Sub New()' in designer-generated type 'WindowsApplication7.CustomPictureBox' should call InitializeComponent method.`
///
`- Error 1 Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' specified for class 'CustomPictureBox' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' of one of its other partial types.`

Comment: @user3902533: You should leave the form code as is. Create a new class, called CustomPictureBox, it will be in its own separate file CustomPictureBox.vb. Build the project. Drop this new control on the form. Form will have no code at this point, only what's in designer, but you don't write it anyway. Start the project, you should see the results on the screen.

Comment: its late where I am now and i'm a bit confused (sorry). From the beginning : I created a new project. I added a PictureBox in the design. I created a new class called CustomPictureBox where i copied the code you submitted. Then what ? Because when i build and debug, nothing happens

Comment: @user3902533: You created a new project. Do not add anything in designer yet. Create a custom class called CustomPictureBox and copy the code above into it. Build the project. You should see a new control appear in the toolbox. It's not a picture box control, it's another one. Drop that onto the form. That's it. Start program (F5) and enjoy!