# Rotating a picture in the picturBox to make it look like a 3D effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to rotate the picture in order to make it look like a 3D effect, I am using the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Point[]) and I am having a real problem in fixing the new points.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point[] destinationPoints = {
new Point(200, 20),   // destination for upper-left point of 
                      // original
new Point(110, 100),  // destination for upper-right point of 
                      // original
new Point(250, 30)};  // destination for lower-left point of 
                      // original
        if (pictureBox.Image != null)
        {

            Image image = new Bitmap(this.imageFiles[(this.selected) % this.imageFiles.Length]);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox.Image);
            //  pictureBox.Image = null;
            // Draw the image unaltered with its upper-left corner at (0, 0).
            // g.DrawImage(image,150, 150);

            // Draw the image mapped to the parallelogram.
            g.Clear(pictureBox.BackColor);
            g.DrawImage(image, destinationPoints);
            pictureBox.Refresh();
            //   Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(image);
            //  image = RotateImage(image2,0 );
            //  g.Dispose();
            //pictureBox.Invalidate();
            //  pictureBox.Image = image2;


        };
```

Any help ?
[Example :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEtg6.jpg)

Comment: This kind of rotation is not supported in GDI+. You need to look fo an external library!

Comment: try here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25349963/3279496 ... and here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ... using *"skew"* for Your example.